# How to remove/change the border when clicking inside an input field in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I used this but it didn't work.

```
input[type="email"],
input[type="password"],
textarea,
select {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the border of the input or the dotted line when the input gets focus?

Comment: yeah that's. when you click on a input box, it gives you a blue outline by default. It easily removes in normal css but not in Bootstrap

Answer (score 6):

These styles disable the blue color:

If you use forms with all fields having the `form-control` class (the Bootstrap way), we can overwrite these things for the focus event:

```css
form .form-control:focus{
  border-color: #ced4da;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Example multiple select</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the CSS below to remove outline in Bootstrap 3 and 4. This will remove the outline for all `input` fields that contain `form-control` class. If you want to apply this to a specific `input` field, use its `id` instead of the `form-control` class.

```
.form-control:focus{
    border-color:#CCC;
    outline:0;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
 .form-control:focus{
        box-shadow: none;
    }
```